# `for` loop using generators, return different value if exhausted

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, generator

I am looping over an `itertools.permutation` object and for efficiency, the loop breaks once the item is found. I understand that because I used the `for` loop I am unable to catch the `StopIteration` error when the generator is exhausted and the item is not found.

So far I have implemented a `found` flag, but it seems kinda hacky.

```
from itertools import permutations

def verify_string(name, compare):
    name = name.lower().split()
    compare = compare.lower().split()
    p = permutations(compare, len(compare))
    found = 0

    for i in p:
        if list(i) == name:
            print(f'Found: {compare} in {name}')
            found = 1
            break

    if not found:
        print('Not Found')

name = 'guido van rossum'
compare = 'van guido rossum'

verify_string(name, compare)
>>Found: ['van', 'guido', 'rossum'] in ['guido', 'van', 'rossum']
```

I also thought of checking `if not next(p, '')` to see if it is exhausted but the item might be found in the generator's last item and will return `True` anyways.

*From a Pythonic view, is there a way to manage looping over a generator that **stops and return when an item is found** and **returns a different value only when the generator is exhausted.***

Comment: As a side comment, it is better to cast `name` as a tuple and test for `i == name`. This way, you can avoid creating a redundant copy of each permutation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pythonic way is to use a `for-else` loop.

```
from itertools import permutations

def verify_string(name, compare):
    name = name.lower().split()
    compare = compare.lower().split()    
    for i in permutations(compare, len(compare)):
        if list(i) == name:
            print(f'Found: {compare} in {name}')
            break
    else:  # Raymond Hettinger calls this "if no break" condition
        # If we did not break out of the "for loop", execute this.
        print('Not Found')

name = 'guido van rossum'
compare = 'van guido rossum'

verify_string(name, compare)
>>> Found: ['van', 'guido', 'rossum'] in ['guido', 'van', 'rossum']
```

### Edit

My initial reply was to how to avoid using the `found` flag and I wasn't paying attention to what you were actually trying to do. The `for-else` construct is also a very useful and often neglected language construct that I wanted to highlight.

However, if you **just** want to check if the set of string is a permutation of another, then why not just

```
match = sorted(name.lower().split()) == sorted(compare.lower().split())
```

This avoids the need to go through all possible permutation of the words in the string.

Comment: Lol that is so true, that was my earlier code without the `break` and it kept printing because of that. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This is nice but I would prefer checking `if tuple(name) in permutations(compare, len(compare))` as opposed to the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was not paying attention to the string permutation problem too. Rather just trying to understand the best way to loop over a generator finding for values, you answered the *question* clearly with the `for-else` construct which I misunderstood earlier.

Comment: @BernardL that is my take too. Also, we can consider replacing `sorted` with `set` or `Counter` for better time complexity, at least on paper.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko We cannot use a `set` because the string might have repeated words.

Comment: Yes, in that case `collections.Counter` is appropriate.

Comment: I doubt `if tuple(name) in permutations(compare, len(compare))`  will work? `permutations` returns a generator and you can't check for membership.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko go ahead and post your updated answer with that and I will gladly +1 for a workable solution.

Comment: @BernardL updated. Feel free incorporate any bits if you like; looks like your answer will show up for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. One is to test a membership of an iterator:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import Counter


def verify_string(name, compare):
    if tuple(compare.lower().split()) in permutations(name.lower().split()):
        print(f"Found: {compare} in {name}")
    else:
        print("No match found")
```

We can also avoid the function altogether with a ternary operator:

```
val if val in itr else other_val
```

If the iterator at hand happens to be the `permutations`, then we can get away without considering every permutation and count words instead.

```
def verify_string_fast(name, compare):
    if not Counter(compare.lower.split()) - Counter(name.lower.split()):
        print(f"Found: {compare} in {name}")
    else:
        print("No match found")
```

More generally, if we have a test condition other than membership, we can do:

```
def verify_general(val, itr):
    if any(compare(val, x) for x in itr):
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failure")
```

---

Note on membership in an iterator. According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations),

> For user-defined classes which do not define **contains**() but do
>   define **iter**(), x in y is True if some value z with x == z is
>   produced while iterating over y. If an exception is raised during the
>   iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.

Since `permutations` has an `__iter__` method, testing for membership is possible.

For example,

```
assert (3, 2, 1) in permutations([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: The results do not really matter for this question, as long as the generator stops when the criteria are matched. And how would I use `itertools.chain` for my problem statement?

Comment: I think that I was focusing on the details of the example too much. See if the first snipped added in the last edit does the job.

Comment: Do you mean to convert, `list(permutations(name.lower.split()))`? Tested and membership testing with generators does not work. For the `Counter` method, why are you doing an equality test? And where did you define the function `compare` in `verify_general`.

Comment: @BernardL there was a typo in my code; `permutations(name.lower.split()` should be `permutations(name.lower().split()`. For the details of how testing iterator membership works, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations I did not define compare, it's meant to be pseudocode for a boolean binary predicate.

Comment: The inequality check for Counter comparison comes into play if `compare` has fewer words than `name`, but every word in `compare` is a word in `name`.

Comment: A generator, which is an iterator does not have the `__contain__` method and therefore using `in` on the object will not work. You have to iterate over the `object` if you want to use `in`. An a `Counter`  object does not support `<=` operators.

Comment: You are right about the Counter not supporting `__leq__` - I must have imagined the check for partial order. You can get around this by checking if `ctr1 - ctr2` is empty, as in the update. Your claim about `__contains__` is not correct; you can see the link in the previous comment or the updated answer.

Comment: Dude, test your code, `dir(permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))` and read the docs:  For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`.

Comment: @BernardL that's exactly what I mean. The point is that you don't need a `for` loop and use `in` instead. This is roughly twice as fast on my machine. Both iterate over permutations, but using `in` takes advantage of internal optimizations.

Comment: `in` does not work, it is clear that you when checking for a `permutation` item class, it does not have a `__contains__()` method, `item` in `permutation(..)` just does not work.

Comment: The exact line `assert (3, 2, 1) in permutations([1, 2, 3])` works on my machine in Python 3.6.2. The docs say that this is supported at least since 2.7.15 or 3.5; at any rate, I am not claiming that `__contains__` method is ever called. Instead, `x in itr` is re-written to something like `any(x == i for i in itr)`. All I am saying is that this is supported behavior and imo is preferable to using a for loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184594/discussion-between-bernardl-and-yakym-pirozhenko).

Answer (score 1):

> From a Pythonic view, is there a way to manage looping over a
>   generator that stops and return when an item is found and returns a
>   different value only when the generator is exhausted.

As you don't actually return anything - if you fix that part of your function, you'll return `None` if there are no matches:

```
from itertools import permutations

def verify_string(name, compare):
    name = name.lower().split()
    compare = compare.lower().split()    
    for i in permutations(compare, len(compare)):
        if list(i) == name:
            return True

name = 'guido van rossum'
compare = 'van guido rossum'

if verify_string(name, compare):
  print(f'Found: {compare} in {name}')
else:
  print('Not found')
```

Comment: That's true, I was just juggling with the thoughts of whether to manage it in the function or not.